How to hide the label on the right side of the ImGui::SliderInt(...)

enum ImGuiSliderFlags_
{
    ImGuiSliderFlags_None               = 0,
    ImGuiSliderFlags_Logarithmic        = 1 << 5,       // Make the widget logarithmic (linear otherwise). Consider using ImGuiSliderFlags_NoRoundToFormat with this if using a format-string with small amount of digits.
    ImGuiSliderFlags_NoRoundToFormat    = 1 << 6,       // Disable rounding underlying value to match precision of the display format string (e.g. %.3f values are rounded to those 3 digits).
    ImGuiSliderFlags_NoInput            = 1 << 7,       // Disable CTRL+Click or Enter key allowing to input text directly into the widget.
    ImGuiSliderFlags_WrapAround         = 1 << 8,       // Enable wrapping around from max to min and from min to max. Only supported by DragXXX() functions for now.
    ImGuiSliderFlags_ClampOnInput       = 1 << 9,       // Clamp value to min/max bounds when input manually with CTRL+Click. By default CTRL+Click allows going out of bounds.
    ImGuiSliderFlags_ClampZeroRange     = 1 << 10,      // Clamp even if min==max==0.0f. Otherwise due to legacy reason DragXXX functions don't clamp with those values. When your clamping limits are dynamic you almost always want to use it.
    ImGuiSliderFlags_AlwaysClamp        = ImGuiSliderFlags_ClampOnInput | ImGuiSliderFlags_ClampZeroRange,
    ImGuiSliderFlags_InvalidMask_       = 0x7000000F,   // [Internal] We treat using those bits as being potentially a 'float power' argument from the previous API that has got miscast to this enum, and will trigger an assert if needed.
};

I couldn't find an example in the demo code, which one should I use?

If I am correct, everything right of '##' in your label is not displayed. So 'play##foo' shows just 'play' and '##playfoo' does not show a label at all. The whole label is used though as ID by ImGui to uniquely identify the widget.
